# Can't extract archives in GUI anymore

Tags: archive, extract

I could always easily extract archives (like .tar.xz and etc.) via the GUI... All I had to do was to right-click the archive and select "Extract here" and it would extract the archive in a sec... but since yesterday, this option's been missing... There's no "Extract here" option when i right-click the archive! I can still extract archives using the terminal with `tar -xf` command though, but it would be much easier if I could do this as before.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? What is DE? Is file-roller installed?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install xarchiver`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably can be fixed by

```
sudo apt-get install file-roller
```

Comment: Looks like Archive Manager was removed for some reason and i didn't notice! I did as you said and Archive Manager is installed now, problem solved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Excellent. In fact this solution solve my other problem. The default app xarchiver  for extracting compressed file work very slow. In a version of Debian without it install `file-roller` work fine.